# How to log .net events and exceptions in google analytics?

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics

I'm using following code for tracking my event using javascript :

```
(function () {
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', googleAnalyticsAppID, 'auto', { 'cookieDomain': 'none' });
ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
ga('send', 'pageview');
})();

window.onload = function () {
$('.googleAnalytics').click(function () {
    var event = this.getAttribute("ga-event");
    var category = this.getAttribute("ga-category");
    var label = this.getAttribute("ga-label");        
    gaWeb(category, event, label);        
});
};


function gaWeb(category, event, label) {
   ga('send', 'event', category, event, label);
}

function gaPageView(page, title) {
   ga('send', 'pageview', {
    'page': page,
    'title': title
});
}
```

The same implementation i want to do in my C# coding, where I can log my exception in google events. 
is there any prebuild library availbale in .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've extended my own class over Logger.Net to log in both file system and google analytics.

source: https://askgif.com/blog/214/how-can-i-log-net-events-and-exceptions-in-google-analytics/

you can use following class :

```
namespace M2E.Common.Logger
{
public class Logger : ILogger
{
    private string _currentClassName;        
    bool GALoggin;
    ILog logger = null;
    public Logger(string currentClassName)
    {
        this._currentClassName = currentClassName;
        GALoggin = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GALogging"]);

        logger = LogManager.GetLogger(_currentClassName);
        BasicConfigurator.Configure();
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();


    }

    public void Info(string message)
    {
        if (GALoggin && Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GAInfoLogging"]))
        {                
            TrackGoogleEvents("Logger-Info", "Info", message);               
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Info(message);
        }
    }

    public void Error(string message, Exception ex)
    {
        if (GALoggin)
        {
            TrackGoogleEvents("Logger-Error", message, ex.Message.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Error(message, ex);
        }
        try
        {
            SendAccountCreationValidationEmail.SendExceptionEmailMessage(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExceptionsSendToEmail"].ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    public void Debug(string message, Exception ex)
    {
        if (GALoggin)
        {
            TrackGoogleEvents("Logger-Debug", message, ex.Message.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Debug(message, ex);
        }                  
    }

    public void Fatal(string message, Exception ex)
    {
        if (GALoggin)
        {
            TrackGoogleEvents("Logger-Fatal", message, ex.Message.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Fatal(message, ex);
        }              
    }

    private void TrackGoogleEvents(string category, string action, string label)
    {
        try
        {
            AsyncTrackGoogleEvents(category, action, label); // to make it async call if required..
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Fatal("Google Analytics Event Tracking Exception", ex);
        }

    }

    public void AsyncTrackGoogleEvents(string category, string action, string label)
    {
        var googleEvent = new GoogleEvent("MadeToEarn.com", category, action, label, 1);
        var requestEvent = new RequestFactory().BuildRequest(googleEvent);
        GoogleTracking.FireTrackingEvent(requestEvent);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Would be useful if you attached what the GoogleTracking/GoogleEvent namespaces are and where to find them. I can't find them on a nuget search. Can you help me with this?

Comment: @rolls GoogleAnalyticsDotNet is the package.  I had to search for it too.

Comment: And make sure to add `<add key="GoogleAnalyticsAccountCode" value="UA-XXXXXXXXX-X"/>` to your config, otherwise it will not work.